# How can i do an echo pop up instead of opening in new tab?

Tags: php, html, forms

I created an email form and after the submit button is pressed I want a pop up to appear, not open a new tab.
This is the form:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
    <input class="inputForm" type="text" name="name" id="nameInput" placeholder="name*">
    <input class="inputForm" type="text" name="email" id="emailInput" placeholder="email*">
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="message*"></textarea>
    <input id="submitButton" type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the php for it:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "New message";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);
echo "Your message has been sent!";

?>
```

Comment: Sidenote: `From:` expects an email address and not a name http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: Yes, it is true but i was not asking that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is technically an alert, but here you go!

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "New message";

mail ($to, $subject, $message, "From: " . $name);
echo('<script>
alert("Your message has been sent!")
</script>')
?>
```

I think this is what you were asking for, but if you were asking for something else, I hope you find it!

Comment: Ok it works but it still redirects me to the php page

Comment: @CatalinSandu I'm sorry, but the only way you can solve that is by using ajax. The form is client-side and the php is server-side so you have to redirect for the php to work. This is the best you can do without using ajax.

Comment: Oh i see. Thank you very much! I have one more question if you don't mind. How can i allow my $name to have space between words?

Comment: Actually @CatalinSandu, I don't know if it's too late, but if you add meta info to your head on your php file, you can redirect it. It would look a bit like this:  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/'" >`

Comment: Ok @Bob the Coder. I will try it